# Goldwater Scholarship and Computer Science

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science

Does having a Goldwater scholarship increase your chances of graduate school admissions in top computer science programs? If it does matter, how much?

Answer (score 1):

It probably is a positive line on your CV. How much it matters however will vary depending on the rest of your CV and where you apply. It is impossible to say things like: "having this scholarship will increase your chances by 10%".

My advice: focus less on the fact that you got the scholarship (simply mentioning it is enough) and start thinking more about why you got it. Did you do anything extraordinary (projects, exceptional grades, extra curriculars, etc.)? Make sure you mention those and why they set you apart from your fellow students. Are there staff members who are very enthusiastic about you? Make sure you include letter of recommendations from them.